# Regex doesent match

Tags: java, regex

I´m new to coding in Java and am currently trying to use regex pattern matches. But for some reason the regex just wont match anything.
My code is as the following:

```
if(scan.hasNext("append\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*")){
    //do stuff
}
```

but if I input "append hello", it won´t match.

Could someone please tell me why?

Comment: See [Trying to read 2 words from a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702124/trying-to-read-2-words-from-a-file-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `matches` for example :

```
"append hello".matches("append\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

---

You can use :

```
if (scan.nextLine().matches("append\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

Comment: this results in the compiling error: cannot find symbol, do i need to import something?

Comment: i think you mis-understoud something, check my edit, `scan.hasNext` return true so you can't use matches with it, you can use `scan.nextLine().matches("append\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*")` instead @CharlieTr

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default delimiter for a `Scanner` (Which I assume is `scan`) is a space, so the tokens become: `append` and `hello`, and neither matches the pattern.

You can set the delimiter to something else, for instance a line separator:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());

if (scan.hasNext("append\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) {
    // ...
}
```

Now when I input `append hello`, I do get a match.